# Measure real memory consumption of a .NET application process

Tags: .net, memory, process, ram, memory-consumption

I'm trying to find out the real memory consumption of a .NET application process. Not how much memory is reserved for the application, but the lowest amount possible that the application needs to run without having to start paging.

It is an application which will be shared and run by multiple users on a Citrix server, which is why I need to make a good estimation of the consumption since I will have to see how much RAM I need for a specific amount of users.

Are there any specific formulas I could apply, or a tool which would allow me to see this?

I tried implementing the following formula, but the results returned are not really reliable, and the formula itself may be, with high probability, erronous.

Using the process explorer, and going to Physical Memory, I used:

Memory Priority
Working Set
Peak Working Set

X = Working Set - Working Set Shared, where X is the result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My experience you you need to use a memory profiler.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers/206760#206760